# C++11 thread: start in constructor and join in destructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to declare C++11 thread as a class member, so that I can "assign" the function to begin execution, say in the constructor and I can join the thread in the destructor.

How would I go about this? I have declared the threads as members, but I am struggling with assigning the function for the thread to invoke?

Pseudo:

```
class X{
public:
    X(){  
        t1(&X::func, this);
        t2(&X::func, this);
    }

    ~X(){
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }

    void func(){
        //Does stuff
    }

   std::thread t1;
   std::thread t2;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Initialise them in the constructor's initialiser list in the usual manner:

```
X() : t1(&X::func, this), t2(&X::func, this) {}
```

or, to make sure all members are initialised first, leave them default-initialised, then reassign them in the constructor's body:

```
X(){
    t1 = std::thread(&X::func, this);
    t2 = std::thread(&X::func, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&X::func` is not a callable object, but rather a member function offset. You must use a bound member function pointer to achieve the result you're after.